# Connect to nodejs through public ip address

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, node.js

I have a basic node express app running on port 3000.
I can access it via **127.0.0.1:3000**, my private ip is **192.168.1.2**
I've set up portforwarding in my d-link router as followed:

```
Private IP       Protocol Type     Public Start Port   Public End Port  Connection      
192.168.1.2      ALL               3000                3000             PVC0
```

When I try access via "public_ip":3000 I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I disabled router firewall and windows firewall to cross them out as the problem, and I've used an online port scanner to make sure the port is open.

Any one know what the problem could be?

Comment: Most routers for home use doesn't allow you to access it from the *"outside"*. You can usually get around it by connecting to your own public IP through a http-proxy. One free proxy you can try is http://hideme.be/